# Docu sign REST Api - trying to add a user to a group its giving 404 exception

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to assign a group to a user using below URL :

https://api-d.docusign.net/management/v2/organizations/hello-3c3a-4009d-198a-gh67749d031w/groups/Administrators/users

We have a group called *'Administrators'* that exists in `Docusign`, trying assign a user: TestUser003

below are body parameters:

```
{"users": 
[{"userId": "TestUser003"}]}
```

under the header I have below :

```
Authorization: Bearer ey************
Content-Type: application/json
```

It's giving `404 - Not Found` error, any idea what am missing?

Comment: where did you find this endpoint? it's not something I can find in the documentation so I think it's incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Updating a user is done using this endpoint - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/admin-api/reference/users/users/updateuser/

Which is:

```
POST /v2/organizations/{organizationId}/users/profiles
```

In the body you can update various things about the user including their membership in groups.